# Having overlay in Android Camera Preview

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to implement an overlay like this picture below in camera preview. 
[image: Picture with camera overlay in android camera preview]

My xml look like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="399dp" >
</FrameLayout>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:text="@string/share" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_capture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
    android:text="@string/capture" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

If I try to use **listview** in **framelayout** it doesn't show it camera preview after executing my code. Any idea how can have such overlay in camera preview ?

Answer (score 0):

I added a button on top of a camera preview for my app. I found the solution to avoid using XML altogether and just program it in. this may be of use to you.

The camera class extends Fragment. but you can see here the button is created then added to the view. after the camera surface view.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_fragment,
                container, false);

        myCamera = getCameraInstance();

        recording = false;

        if (myCamera == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Fail to get Camera",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        Button button = new Button(getActivity());

        //button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.record);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        params.width = 260;
        params.height = 260;
        button.setLayoutParams(params);
        button.setText("Record");

        myCameraSurfaceView = new GetCamera(getActivity(), myCamera);

        ((ViewGroup) rootView).addView(myCameraSurfaceView);
        ((ViewGroup) rootView).addView(button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);

        return rootView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an App I developed. I needed buttons on the camera preview.
All I did is in the xml layout, on whatever View item you want - just add the attribute

```
android:alpha"0.5"
```

where 0.5 is 50% transparent

Good luck